# Как получить номер текущего элемента массива (при его обработке во внешнем цикле) в переменную ? -caroufredsel+Javascript+php

Tags: php, javascript, java, wordpress

на сайте под wordpress, задана смена цитат следующим способом:
в центральной странице есть код:

```
<div class="t-quote animated fadeInUp">
      <?php the_field('default_quote'); ?>
</div>
<div class="hide quote-block">
     <?php
         if ( have_rows('quote') ):
            while ( have_rows('quote') ) : the_row();
     ?>
              <div class="quote-text"><?php the_sub_field('quote_text'); ?></div>
     <?php
             endwhile;
         endif;
     ?>
</div>
```

есть также javascript:

```
  $('.slider-bg ul').carouFredSel({
    items: 1,
    pagination: {
      container: '.pager',
      anchorBuilder: function(nr) {
        return "<a href='#' class='pag'><i class='fa fa-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    auto: { timeoutDuration: 5000 },
    scroll: {
      items: 1,
      fx: "crossfade",
      duration: 1000,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      onAfter: function(t) {
        var quote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
        $('.t-quote').html("<div class='animated fadeInUp'>" + quote + "</div>");
      }
    }
  });
```

Прошу посоветовать как вместо `var quote = quotes[ рандомное число]` подставить текущий индекс отрабатываемого массива, что-нибудь простое и  элегантное, типа, как в PHP: `getRowIndex()`, чтобы цитаты всплывали не случайно, а последовательно. Я не программист, но хочу разобраться.

Comment: Java SE тут где?

Comment: Задачи на fl.ru, а здесь вопросы. Покажите что сделали вы.

Comment: Уважаемый, эта задача и была разработана на fl,ru . моего кода здесь нет, но мне надо ее поправить, поможете ?

Comment: @LAndrey обратитесь к тому, кто вам это сделал на fl.ru? ;)

Comment: Я что , не имею права разобраться в коде самостоятельно ? Да , у меня, считай,  0й уровень программирования, по сравнению с вами, Гуру, которые имеют право судить, Но где в правилах написан ценз уровня на входе, чтобы задавать вопросы ?

Comment: @LAndrey Конечно, имеете право самостоятельно разобраться. Вот и разбирайтесь. Здесь показывают то, что самостоятельно сделали или попытались сделать. А с такими "вопросами" вам на fl.ru дорога.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var currentQuote = 0; // Индекс текущей цитаты. Начало - 0
   $('.slider-bg ul').carouFredSel({
    items: 1,
    pagination: {
      container: '.pager',
      anchorBuilder: function(nr) {
        return "<a href='#' class='pag'><i class='fa fa-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>";
      }
    },
    responsive: true,
    auto: { timeoutDuration: 5000 },
    scroll: {
      items: 1,
      fx: "crossfade",
      duration: 1000,
      pauseOnHover: false,
      onAfter: function(t) {
        var quote = quotes[currentQuote];
        // Если текущая цитата последняя, сбрасываем индекс в начало, иначе прибавляем 1
        currentQuote = (currentQuote == quotes.length - 1) ? 0 : currentQuote+1;  последняя, 
        $('.t-quote').html("<div class='animated fadeInUp'>" + quote + "</div>");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, изящно и работает!  я бы сам долго мучился. Не понял я за что мне бал снизили, ведь "самый глупый вопрос- незаданный".Но все же , как я вычитал, такого метода для снятия  мгновенного "снимка " текущего индекса массива не существует (или как кто-то здесь http://www.cyberforum.ru/javascript/thread867223.html написал "курсор массива") ?  - только через перебирающие методы , как типа arr.forEach() или arr.indexof() или через такой цикл , как у Вас.

Comment: Изначально вопрос выглядел как задача. А тут любителей бесплатно получить код полно. потом, видимо, поправили вопрос и на него получилось ответить. Перебирающие функции тут не понадобились, потому что onAfter выполняется каждую итерацию. Просто нужно было указать нужный элемент в момент смены слайда.